# Vuex: handle async action with promise call to REST API

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, vue.js, action, vuex

I use TypeScript with Vue/Vuex to create a toy app, in which I need to load a list of items from remote API upon rendering a component. In the actions below, I use the library `axios` to make http request, and I return it as a promise:

```
const actions = {    
  getCurrentSession(context: Context) {
    return axios.get("http://localhost:3000/sessions/current")
      .then((res) => {
        commitSharedFiles(context, res.data.shared_files);
      })
      .catch((e: string) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
  }
};

// export action
export const dispatchGetSharedFiles = dispatch(actions.getCurrentSession);

// commit
export const commitSharedFiles = commit(mutations.setSharedFileList);

// mutations to the state tree
const mutations = {
  setSharedFileList(state: State, sharedFiles: StoreState.DirFile[]) {
    state.sharedFileList = sharedFiles;
  }
};
```

Because of the asynchronous nature of the actions, I have to resolve the promise before retrieving the fetched list of files from the store/state tree:

```
// this is called in the mounted() life cycle method:
Store.dispatchGetSharedFiles(this.$store).then(res => {
            this.sharedFiles = Store.readSharedFilesList(this.$store);
});
```

This works, but I think it is very convoluted to resolve the promise and then get the data. Is there a better way to use async actions in Vuex? thanks

Comment: Looks like you've implemented the [explicit promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Don't do that

Comment: thanks i just removed the Promise wrapper :)

Comment: What is `commit` in the context of your code snippet? Same for `dispatch`? The whole `commitSharedFiles` bit doesn't make much sense. You're calling it as a function but it doesn't appear to be one, unless `commit(...)` somehow returns a function

Comment: commit returns a function committing mutation directed to the specified mutation handler. `dispatch` dispatching action directed to the specified action handler. thanks

Comment: Could you please show those implementations? Your question doesn't make much sense without them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `async/await` for the action and a mapped `getter` for retrieving the items from the store (could map an action also).

```
// store.ts
const actions = {    
  async FetchSharedFiles(context: Context) {
    // omitted error handling for brevity
    let {res} = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/sessions/current")
    commitSharedFiles(context, res.data.shared_files);
  }
};

// component.ts
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
...
mounted () {
  // again, do any necessary error handling
  this.$store.dispatch('FetchSharedFiles')
},
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    sharedFiles: 'namespace/getSharedFiles'
  })
}
```

Using this pattern benefits from vuex's reactivity so `sharedFiles` in your component would trigger an update when the action finishes and commits the response data. Your template then might look like:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(file, i) in sharedFiles" :key="i">
    // layout for each item...
  </div>
</template>
```